# Rails 5 console in production not reading database password from environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell

I am running a Rails application on Apache with passenger in production mode.

Application's database password is getting set using `SetEnv` directive and working fine. The entry for this in `database.yml` is:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  username: app_dbuser
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DBPASSWORD'] %>
```

I want to run rails console for production, so I have set above variable like this in my current shell:

```
export APP_DBPASSWORD="secret"
```

and then I am starting console and trying to access any record, but it is giving error:

```
$ bin/rails c production
Running via Spring preloader in process 8813
Loading production environment (Rails 5.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> Client.first
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'app_dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

However, in console `ENV['APP_DBPASSWORD']` returns proper value, please suggest.

Comment: Kill spring and try once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DNNX pointed out, disabling Spring worked for me:

```
$ DISABLE_SPRING=1 bin/rails c production
```